# Is my model overfitting or underfitting ? .How to identify it from this loss curve?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, overfitting-underfitting

I have created a model based on the mobileNet architecture to classify images. I have used 209222 images for training and 40000 images for validation. After I trained the model the loss curve looks like below. Is this model overfitting or underfitting ? or as the validation and training loss curves are closer to each other and they are flat after some point, can I get this as a good model?. I have attached my loss curves below.
[loss curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tktSJ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If loss is less then that means your solution might be converging. As your val_loss and train_loss don't have that much difference and both are converging then that implies that your model is not overfitting